# how to monitor the subprocess realtime

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, monitor, interactive

I am a newbie to python.

I am working on a project currently.

by clicking a button A, the command "adb shell getevent" will be executed in one subprocess.
the result will be write to a file.
There will be result from time to time if someone tap on the devices connected.

It will be stopped by clicking a Button B.

```
class MyClass():
...
    def recordCmd(self):
        cmd = []
        cmd.append("adb")
        cmd.append("shell")
        cmd.append("getevent")
        cmd.append("/dev/input/event0")
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        for line in p.stdout:
            print line

    def OnRecordEvent(self, event):
    '''
     call "adb shell getevent /dev/input/event0 " to collect events
     '''
    mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.recordCmd, args=(self,))
    mp.daemon= True
    mp.start()
....
```

This doesn't work, the following errors are thrown:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 271, in __init__
dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 193, in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
self.save(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
save(state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
save(v)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 66, in dispatcher
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
save(args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
save(element)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
save(state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
save(v)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
save(state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
save(v)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
save(cls)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
(obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'PySwigObject'>: it's not found as __builtin__.PySwigObject
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` when copying objects between processes. The error message seems to indicate that `MyClass` contains something that can't be pickled.

You could take the `recordCmd` function out of the class, as it is not referencing `self` anyway.